# SeeTest launch status error

Tags: android, python, testing, automation

I am using SeeTest Automation trial version.

I wrote python code for using seeTest client class.
SeeTest start correctly and runs a few tests. But suddenly, I get an error about launch.

> launch
>
> status:false

When I restart the seeTest Automation program, SeeTest launchs with no problem. After that I run the same tests, but later on, I get the same status error (But at another test)

My code is here:

```
self.client.launch(args[current["device_OS"] + "_activity_name"], True, False)
```

Is that something to do with that I'm using trial version instead of full version of SeeTest? What am I missing?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's about trial version. There are restriction.
Upgrading to paid version solve my problem.